# ffmpeg webm (codec vp9) to mp4 not working on all browsers

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm recording a video from chrome browser in webm format and on the backend side I want to convert it into mp4 so it can be played back on all devices. The video has this sample name: `test.webm;codecs_vp9;`

I first used this command to convert it to mp4 but the output was not working for safari web and mobile (Video was not loading inside the player) but it was working properly on chrome:

```
ffmpeg -i "test.webm;codecs_vp9;" -c  copy -strict experimental -preset superfast testout.mp4
```

I tried removing the `-strict experimental` but nothing happened.

Then I updated the the command with following configs and the output was then working for ios and web safari but it stopped working properly for chrome. On chrome it was jumpy (missing frames, getting stopped at some intervals), and the audio and video are not synced.

```
ffmpeg -i "test.webm;codecs_vp9;" -strict experimental -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset superfast -profile:v main -movflags faststart -level 3.0 testout.mp4
```

I want it to be working on both browsers and platforms.

I'm using ffmpeg static builds downloaded from here: https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: In the first command you are simply copying the streams without transcoding, so the options apart `-c copy` are useless. In the second command you are transcoding to h264 and aac, but do you have any motivation for all these options apart from `-acodec aac -vcodec libx264`? If "no", just start from the simplest command and see what happens.

Comment: In the second command if I remove the other options it doesn't work on safari and ios

Comment: OK... Have you tried the "Baseline" profile, and/or lowering the level ?

Comment: Baseline made no efect. I've reduced the command to this: ```ffmpeg -i "nick.webm;codecs_vp9;" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 testout.mp4``` But still it is jumpy on chrome.

Comment: this worked. Not sure why tho: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081437/

Comment: update: that fixed the issue for chrome and safari web but on ios its still playable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the command given below to be able to playback the output video on ios, android, chrome and safari.

```
ffmpeg -i "test.webm;codecs_vp9;" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt:v yuv420p -movflags +faststart -vsync vfr testout.mp4
```